# Best way to deal with minor edits

Tags: discussion

My feelings say : it is not the right time ... but my brain says : it is the right time ! to post.

Last night, the suggested review queue hits more than usual number. I observed a (new)user doing all the edits and all are with `eos --> elementary OS`. (I approved all the edits except one or two). I considered the above case as **an example** for better understanding, *Please never mind*.

*My question*:

What should be correct choice, if the post is too minor and If there are other things that could be "corrected" ?

> [image: Approve, Improve Edit, Reject and Edit, Skip]

**Minor**: Definition of  the word "minor" varies widely.

Here are some instances I will mention:

- Removing **only** "Thanks"
- changing **only** eos --> elementary OS
- Also  minor as defined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review)

I remember I have posted [similar post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14557/edit-that-removes-only-thanks-from-post-should-it-be-approved-or-rejected) on other SE site.

---

Here are my references from main meta:

[Is correcting a common misspelling too minor an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147946/is-correcting-a-common-misspelling-too-minor-an-edit)

[Does Stack Exchange have an official stance on users doing a large number of trivial edits to old questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165878/does-stack-exchange-have-an-official-stance-on-users-doing-a-large-number-of-tri)

---

From help center [edit questions](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

---

*EDIT*:

I have posted this question: To link this post as reasons for rejection in custom message, but not to *belabour* the point :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand and know that SE discourages minor edits, but to me if they are a clear improvement - approve them.

Obviously if the editor could have made further changes, then you should improve them. If the change is not useful or is meaningless - such as if it's eOS to elementary OS, then you should probably reject.

This is one of those things that doesn't take a lot of discussion/belabouring in my opinion.

Comment: I would disagree slightly, if changing eOS to elementary OS is the only obvious improvement to be made, then let them make it. If an edit is only partially complete then it needs improving, but I don't think we should discourage small edits, especially as that's one of the ways people start out helping us.